# OpenJDK 8 for Mac OS is not available

Tags: android, macos

As **android development** is moving from using **OracleJDK** to **OpenJDK**,
I couldn't find **OpenJDK version 8** to install in my **MacOS 10.11.1**.

- I want to know if i'm missing something that i cannot find how to
  install **OpenJDK 8** in Mac?
- Can i use **Oracle JDK 8** instead?
- **this is the end of Android Development on Macs?**

Comment: you don't need the JDK, you just need the Android SDK. Plus, you can build the JDK from source if you did need it. Also, the bold text is really unnecessary

Comment: explain "you don't need the JDK".. how can you make android apps without java?

Comment: Okay, maybe I was thinking the SDK bundled the JDK, but that most likely isn't true. Regardless, my second point still stands

Comment: point me how to build OpenJdk for Mac OSX

Comment: This link. https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/MacOSXPort/Main

Comment: okay i will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html).

From the official docs-

> There are, however, known stability issues in Android Studio on Mac when using JDK 1.8. Until these issues are resolved, you can improve stability by downgrading your JDK to an older version (but no lower than JDK 1.6).

So stay on OracleJDK 1.7

Comment: the question is about installing openjdk 8 and this accepted answer suggests using oraclejdk 1.7 (even though there are ways to setup openjdk 8 on mac). this should not be an accepted answer.